# Facebook application: storing user photo thumbnails

Tags: facebook

I'm building a Facebook app that has (as part of its function) a display of a user's FB photos.  The terms and conditions on this issue are a little fuzzy to me, so I figured I'd ask this here:

Does anyone know if it's acceptable to create thumbnails of their FB photos and store them on my server?  If so (provided I've got offline_access permissions and all that), would I have to refresh it every 24 hours as well?

Thanks much!

Comment: Is there any explicit advantage of storing the photos on your own machine? If you're pulling them from the API anyway it seems like it would just make more sense to use that pattern. I don't know anything about the FB API personally, but I'd wager there's a lot going on in the background to optimize performance on frequent operations like retrieving profile photos.

Comment: We considered that – the real issue is just resizing.  As you've said, the API is great at quickly returning info on photos, people, etc., but the photos aren't being returned in a size that's necessarily helpful to us.  We'd rather not have to resize a whole bunch of stuff on every page load.

Comment: You could try css resizing -- it looks good and doesn't require any extra storage.

Comment: I think that might be what we have to do.  I was hoping to dodge the overhead of resizing on the fly with inconsistently-sized images, but it might be the only kosher solution.  Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, the answer is **No.**

Facebook's [Platform Policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) states:

> You must not store or cache any data
>   you receive from us for more than 24
>   hours unless doing so is permitted by
>   the offline exception, or that data is
>   explicitly designated as Storable
>   Data.

The `offline_access` extended permission actually has no affect on whether you can store any data, you may have confused it with the `offline exception`, which is as follows:

> Offline exception: Applications that
>   run on a device controlled by and
>   possessed by the user -- such as
>   desktop or laptop computer, mobile
>   device, or other embedded device --
>   can cache user data received from
>   Facebook for more than 24 hours only
>   when Internet connectivity is
>   unavailable or it is impossible for
>   the application to run. Such data can
>   be stored on the client device but not
>   a remote server, and cannot be made
>   available to the developer. Cached
>   data older than 24 hours can be
>   displayed to the user (or otherwise
>   used by the application) in lieu of
>   updated data only until an update is
>   possible, and in no case beyond 14
>   days after the last update.

So this means that all you are allowed to store, unless you are covered by the `offline exception`, are the following data fields:

```
User data you receive from Facebook that you can store indefinitely:
uid                    User ID
nid                    Primary network ID
eid                    Event ID
gid                    Group ID
pid                    Photo ID
aid                    Photo album ID
flid                   friend list ID
listing_id             Marketplace listing ID
page_id                Facebook Page ID
proxied_email          Placeholder email addresses for your users
notes_count            Total number of notes written by the user
profile_update_time    Time that the user's profile was last updated
```

Comment: is the solution to make a cronjob script that connects to fb every day, and fetches the users data again? if soo, how can i do that?

Comment: Well you could do that for users that have granted you offline_access, or you can update user info when the user visits the app. You can store the time you last updated the info and do this on a certain interval, i.e. update if it has been more than 24 hours since the last update.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to copy/resize the user's photo, just cache the URL of the photo on Facebook and then use the browser/css to size it to your desired size. Use FQL to query the photo table to get the URL to the full size version (src_big) of the photo. Or query for a smaller size Facebook already created.
This is the url on how to query for the photo url info:
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Photo_%28FQL%29

Comment: That'll work just fine (and is what we ended up doing) — were just hoping we could optimize a bit beyond that.  Thanks tho!